# Total Numbers do not match in reviews

Tags: discussion, bug

NOTE: This question has been marked as a duplicate. Well two things.

1. I don't see an answer there
2. The interpretation of the user in that question is the count of flags is of `available flags` instead of those that are not yet handled by myself. **Is this the case**? If yes, can anyone direct me to a meta/faq link which affirms this? And if you cannot find a meta/faq link then please do not mark it as a duplicate. It is a humble request :)

   Also
3. Instead of simply downvoting, I would request you to please let me know what is wrong with this question so that I can improve on it. :)

---

Please see this screenshot. The numbers never match. No matter how **fast** I refresh.

I thought that maybe there were 7 **Not An Answer** posts and some of them disappeared because they were *actioned* so I **rapidly** refreshed **5 times in a row** but that `7` didn't change... nor did the `3` on the left hand side.

Same with the total posts to be reviewed (in Orange) vs the total posts `19`. The orange total did change after 2 refresh attempts though.

Am I missing something? Does the count for **individual flags** refresh only after some specific time? I assumed it to be dynamic i.e changing with every refresh (Showing the actual count)

[image]

Comment: I've noticed that this happens to the main mod queue too at times.

Comment: @Mr.PeanutMonopolyMcManish Thanks for confirming. :)

Comment: @SiddharthRout - Its talks about the exact same thing. Please read that post a bit more carefully.

Comment: @RJ: Does that mean that there are actually 7 flags and out of those 4 have already been actioned by me and what I see is the remaining flags?

Comment: @RJ: And if yes, then can you direct me to a link which supports that fact. Becuase what is mentioned in that question is OP's own understanding and hence this question is not a duplicate of that.

Comment: @downvoter: Care to explain why did you downvote? Maybe I can then improve my post?